# Extending isomorphism on closed subschemes to open neighborhoods

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X, Y$ be schemes, $Z, Z'$ closed subschemes of $X, Y$ respectively. Assume there is an isomorphism $f: Z\to Z'$, is it possible to find open neighborhoods $U, V$ of $Z, Z'$ respectively such that there is an isomorphism $F: U\to V$ extending $f$? Or under what mild condition such an extension always exists?

I guess we need to assume that $X, Y$ are regular schemes and the inclusion of $Z, Z'$ are regular immersions. In that case it's easily reduced to the case when $Y$ is the total space of the normal bundle $N_{Z/X}$ of $Z$ in $X$ and $Z'$ being the zero section. And then the result would be something like the tubular neighborhood theorem in differential topology. But I can't prove such a tubular neighborhood theorem for (regular closed immersion of) schemes.

Comment: Consider the case where $Z=Z'$ is just a point...

Comment: Another illustrative example is the case where $X=Z=Z'$ is a closed subvariety of $Y$.  A more reasonable idea might be to assume that the isomorphism in question extends to a formal neighborhood of $Z,Z'$; it is still easy to find counterexamples to this version of the question but I would guess that if $Z$ is sufficiently positive (e.g. an ample divisor) one might prove something using, for example, the algebraization techniques from SGA2.

Comment: I would rather look at Nisnevich (i.e., etale) neighbourhoods. Still the corresponding statement is only true for smooth varieties Zariski-locally.